# how to define the static pricing in new payment system and how to pay

Tags: dynamic, callback, payment

how to define the static pricing in new payment system and how to pay?
  I defiened the price (defiend "USD"). But I use sterling to pay , it return error that is '**Sorry, there was a problem and we can’t complete your request. Please try again later**'.Please tell me how to deal with it.
Thanks.

```
<head prefix=
   "og: http://ogp.me/ns# 
    fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
    product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">
   <meta property="og:type"                   content="og:product" />
   <meta property="og:title"                  content="Golds" />
   <meta property="og:image"                  content="http://****/icon_box_1.png" />
   <meta property="og:description"            content="Coins!" />
   <meta property="og:url"                    content="http://****/product.html" /> 
   <meta property="product:price:amount"      content="0.1"/>
   <meta property="product:price:currency"    content="USD"/>
</head>
```